# Can you help me to understand a proof about equivalency of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

The lemma says that if m and n are natural numbers and m not divisible by n and $\zeta_m^j \equiv \zeta_m^k \pmod n$, then $\zeta_m^j = \zeta_m^k$

$\zeta_m$ is here a primitive mth root of unity of the complex numbers so $e^{\frac{2 * \pi * i}{m}}$.

Now the proof is the following: We multiply the conguence by $\zeta_m^{-k}$ and for this reason may assume:

$\zeta_m^j \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and want to prove then that $\zeta_m^j = 1$ this part is no problem... Now:

Because $\prod\limits_{l=1}^{m-1}(x-\zeta_m^l)=(x^m-1)/(x-1)$ we get that  $\prod\limits_{l=1}^{m-1}(1-\zeta_m^l)=m$.

Thus no factor in this last product is zero modulo n, which proves the result.

Now the first product equivalency $\prod\limits_{l=1}^{m-1}(x-\zeta_m^l)=(x^m-1)/(x-1)$ is something I don't get...

But $(x^m-1)/(x-1)$ looks a lot like the solution of $\sum\limits_{l=0}^{m-1}x^l$ (geometric series) and if I insert x=1 in it I indeed get the solution m;

So what I don't understand in particular:

1. The equivalency $\prod\limits_{l=1}^{m-1}(x-\zeta_m^l)=(x^m-1)/(x-1)$... I can clearly see that the zeros of the function are identical but this isn't enough to prove that those polynomials are identical??
2. Can I say $(x^m-1)/(x-1)=\prod\limits_{l=1}^{m-1}x^l$ and then insert x=1.... Because the formula $(x^m-1)/(x-1)$ is just for those $x \neq 1$... And then I insert x=1.... This is confusing
3. "Thus no factor in this last product is zero modulo n, which proves the result." Can someone explain that sentence more detailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me address your numbered list of questions:

1. In general, because of the fundamental theorem of algebra, the zeroes of a polynomial (together with multiplicities of those zeroes) do indeed determine that polynomial *up to scalar multiplication*. To deal with the "up to scalar multiplication" part in your case, we note that both expressions are *monic* polynomials (i.e. coefficient of top-degree term is $1$) - hence they are equal polynomials.
2. I think you wrote the product symbol ($\Pi$) when you meant the sum symbol ($\Sigma$). In any case, yes, you can write $(x^m - 1)/(x-1) = \sum_{l=1}^{m-1}x^l$ and then insert $x = 1$. This is exactly what the author of the proof intended you to do.
3. For this conclusion, the author is referring to the equation $\prod_{l=1}^{m-1}(1-\zeta_m^l) = m$ and essentially saying that since $m$ is not divisible by $n$ (as was assumed at the beginning) it is therefore impossible that *any* of the factors $(1-\zeta_m^l)$ are divisible by $n$ on the left side of the equation. (Remember "divisible by $n$" means the same as "$\equiv 0$ mod $n$"). This then completes the proof because $(1- \zeta_m^l)$ not divisible by $n$ means $1-\zeta_m^l \not\equiv 0$ mod $n$ which means $1 \not\equiv \zeta_m^l$ mod $n$ and thus $\zeta_m^j \not\equiv \zeta_m^{l+j}$ mod $n$ for any $1 \leq j < m$.

Comment: Okay first of all thank you so much for your answer... :) I got number one and number 2 as well, although I still don't know why you are allowed to insert 1 although the formula is for $x \neq 1$... But the 3rd point; Can you explain me first of all what it means that $e{\frac{2 \pi i}{m}}^j$

Comment: Okay first of all thank you so much for your answer... :) I got number one and number 2 as well, although I still don't know why you are allowed to insert 1 although the formula is for $x \neq 1$... But the 3rd point; Can you explain me first of all what it means that $\left(e{\frac{2 \pi i}{m}}\right)^j \equiv 1 \pmod n$ I mean the root of unity is on the unit circle and is complex (if j is not m) so how are you supposed to calculate modulo n here? If I understood that, I probably will also be able to understand the final step...

Comment: Because at the moment I dont get why no factor $1-\zeta_m^l$ can be divisible by n (without the term being 0)

Comment: the 'modulo $n$' relation still works in essentially the same way for complex numbers as it did for integers: if $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, then $z \equiv w$ mod $n$ means that $z = w + kn$ for some *integer* $k$.

Comment: Forget it, I got it... :) Thank you.... I should think first ... Anyway thanks a lot